# What iptables knows about pods?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, iptables

Let's say we have 2 Nodes in a cluster.

`Node A` has 1 replica of a pod, `Node B` has 2 replicas. According to [this talk (YouTube video with a time tag)](https://youtu.be/y2bhV81MfKQ?list=WL&t=1848) from Google Cloud engineers, a request which was routed to `Node A` might be rerouted to the `Node B` by `iptables` which is inside the `Node A`. I have several questions regarding this behavior:

- What information `iptables` of `Node A` knows about replicas of a pod outside of it? How does it know where to send the traffic?
- Can it be that `iptables` of the `Node B` reroutes this request to `Node C`? If so, then will the egress traffic go back to the `Node B` -> `Node A` -> Client?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be mixing up two subsystems, service proxies and CNI. CNI is first, it’s a plug-in based system that sets up the routing rules across all your nodes so that the network appears flat. A pod IP will work like normal from any node. Exactly how that happens varies by plugin, Calico uses BGP between the nodes. Then there’s the service proxies, usually implemented using iptables though also somewhat pluggable. Those define the service IP -> endpoint IP (read: pod IP) load balancing. But the actual routing is handled by whatever your CNI plugin set up. There’s a lot of special modes and cases but that’s the basic overview.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still don't understand the case Google engineers explain. I understand that that behavior can be different from cloud provider to cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

Packets can move between nodes, services and pods before reaching the final destination.

All the intra-cluster routing (node-to-node, pod-to-pod, service-to-service, pod-to-service, service-to-pod, pod-to-node, node-to-pod, etc) in kubernetes is done by:

- CNI
- load-balancing algorithm
- kube-proxy
- iptables.

Packet route in k8s also depends on many things like load in the cluster, per-node load, affinity/anti-affinity rules, nodeSelectors, taints/tolerations, autoscaling, number of pod replicas, etc.

Intra-cluster routing is transparent to the router and ideally the user need not know about it unless there are networking issues to debug.

Doing `sudo iptables -L -n -v` on any k8s node shows the low-level iptables rules and chains used for packet-forwarding.

Comment: I understand that it depends on the network implementation. I'm trying to understand that specific case on the video.